# Controller not working after deploying the application from windows to Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat, virtual-machine

I used Spring in a Java dynamic web project and it works fine on Windows, but after I deployed it to Ubuntu VM the controller doesn't work, I also created a .war file on Eclipse Windows and deployed it via tomcat manager but didn't work.

then I simply copied my src code with the same structure to webapps folder,but seems it shows only .jsp pages, it doesn't map the pages to @requestMapping and call the controller class,  do I need to do any setup/configuration on linux to make it work?

after opening the application, index.jsp shows the content, but after clicking submit it is supposed to call AppDynamicsMain.java controller via `<form class="formcolor" action="tiers" method="GET">` but instead it is looking for tiers page to display and throws HTTP status 404 - not found:

[error page I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KOpA.png)

I have all the required jar files under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/appd-cp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/, do I need to move them $CATALINA_HOME/lib/?

your help is greatly appreciated.

P.S: my VM has no GUI , it is only accessible via terminal(ssh to the ip using mobaXterm)

I had to make an extra index.jsp at the root of my project to make a call to index.jsp in the project jsp folder: $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/appd-cp/index.jsp:

```
<html>
        <head>

           <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp">

        </head>

        <body>
        </body>
</html>
```

index.jsp at WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp:

```
<html>
        <head>

           <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=welcome.jsp">

        </head>

        <body>
        </body>
</html>
```

here is my project structure in VM:

```
   appd-cp
  |->index.jsp
  |->src
  |  -->com.sh
  |     --->AppDynamicsMain.java     
  |->WebContent
  |  -->WEB-INF 
  |     --->jsp
  |         ---->index.jsp
  |         ---->rawDataCPU.jsp
  |         ---->graphCPU.jsp
  |     --->CapacityPlanning-servlet.xml
  |     --->web.xml
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<html>
           <head>
              <title>my title</title>
           </head>
           <style type="text/css">
                        <%@include file="site.css" %>
           </style>
           <body>
             <div id="flip-tabs" >
                <ul id="flip-navigation" >
                    <li><a href="welcome.jsp" id="tab-0">Graph</a></li> &nbsp
                    <li class="selected"><a href="welcomeRawData.jsp" id="tab-1" >Raw Data</a></li> &nbsp
                    <li><a href="#" id="tab-2" >Subscribe</a></li> &nbsp
                </ul>
            </div>    
        <script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";

        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";

        }
        </script>
           <BR><BR><div style="margin-left: 70px;"><p>select the application, parameter and the duration:</p></div>
           <form class="formcolor" action="tiers" method="GET">
           <label>Application: </label>
                                 <select name="application">
                                     <option name="application" value="ALEXA_SKILL">ALEXA_SKILL</option>
                                     <option name="application" value="AMP">AMP</option>
                                </select>
                            <BR>
                            <BR>
                            <label>Parameter: </label>
                            <select name="param">
                                <option name="param" value="CPU">CPU usage</option>
                            </select>
                            <BR>
                            <BR>
                            <label>Duration: </label>
                            <select name="duration">
                                <option name="duration" value="5">5 min</option>
                                <option name="duration" value="15">15 min</option>
                                <option name="duration" value="30">30 min</option>
                            </select>
                            <BR>
                            <BR>
                            <BR>
                            <progress id="p1" max="100" value="0"><span>0</span>%</progress>
                                 <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
           <form>
           </body>
        </html>
```

AppDynamicsMain.java:

```
package com.sh;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.sh.PropertyFileReader;

@Controller
public class AppDynamicsMain {
        protected static final String USERNAME = PropertyFileReader.getAppdUsername();
        protected static final String PASSWORD = PropertyFileReader.getAppdPassword();
        String DestPath = "/root/AppDynamics/";
        public String fileName;
        public String application;
        static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AppDynamicsMain.class.getName());
        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppDynamicsMain.class);
        static String downloadDestPath = "/root/AppDynamics/download/";

        @RequestMapping(value = "tiers" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getContent(@RequestParam(required = true) String application , @RequestParam(required = true) String param, @RequestParam(required = true) String duration,  ModelMap model ) throws IOException{

                logger.info("################### going to call rawData"+ param+ " . . .  " );
                File checkFolder = new File(downloadDestPath);
                   if(checkFolder.isDirectory()){
                           if(checkFolder.list().length>0){
                                   FileUtils.cleanDirectory(checkFolder);
                           }
                         }
                model.addAttribute(application , application);
                model.addAttribute(duration ,  duration);

                return "forward:/rawData"+param;
        }
 @RequestMapping(value = "graphs" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getGraphContent(@RequestParam(required = true) String application , @RequestParam(required = true) String param , ModelMap model ){

                logger.info("################### going to call get"+ param+ " . . .  " );
                model.addAttribute(application , application);

                return "forward:/graph"+param;
        }

   }
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Capacity Forecasting - Planning</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>CapacityPlanning</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>CapacityPlanning</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
        <context-param>
                <param-name>MONGODB_HOST</param-name>
                <param-value>localhost</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
                <param-name>MONGODB_PORT</param-name>
                <param-value>27017</param-value>
        </context-param>
```

CapacityPlanning-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                                                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
                                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package = "com.sh" />

       <bean id = "viewResolver"
             class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
       </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Any errors in the log? I sees an issue with your applicatin. The files under WEB-INF is not accessible from outside world. e.g. `URL=WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp` is not going to work. Can you see if your app deployed successfully? You should be able to package up the .war and deploy to the Apache/Tomcat?

Comment: @MinhKieu, I can access welcome.jsp page, the URL=WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp is being called from index.jsp under the root directory of the project, nothing wrong with accessing the url.

Comment: Can you see if you can access a file from the root folder? As I said and from my experience, contents under the WEB-INF directory cannot be direct access from the outside world. Its is protected by the servlet container. If this is a directory you created manually then I would suggest you check file permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was using duplicate jar files. these spring jar files were in WEB-INF/lib/:

- `spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.release.jar`
- `org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`.

and the root cause of the error was `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.consumes()`, where  `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.class` is a class in both `spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar` and  `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar`, causing initialization to fail. deleting `spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar` solved the issue and app initialized just fine.

```
INFO    2017-09-20 21:50:00,252 [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3917dc5c: defining beans [welcomeController,appTiersHeapMemoryUsed,webController,downloadController,modelController,appTiersMemoryUsage,appDynamicsMain,appTiersCPU,appTiersCurrentHeapMemoryUsage,appTiersTotalMemory,homeController,staticController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO    2017-09-20 21:50:00,351 [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3917dc5c: defining beans [welcomeController,appTiersHeapMemoryUsed,webController,downloadController,modelController,appTiersMemoryUsage,appDynamicsMain,appTiersCPU,appTiersCurrentHeapMemoryUsage,appTiersTotalMemory,homeController,staticController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR   2017-09-20 21:50:00,352 [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.consumes()[Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.consumes()[Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:1)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.matches(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:139)
        at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector$1.doWith(HandlerMethodSelector.java:62)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:473)
        at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods(HandlerMethodSelector.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:71)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 31 more
```